# Best root find algorithm for a sum of a specific exponential functions (Sigmoid functions)?

Tags: algorithms, roots, computational-mathematics

I have to solve a equation of of the form:
\begin{align}
F = f_1 + f_2 + ... + f_{100} = 0.
\end{align}
Where $f_{i}$ $(i = 1,2,...,100)$ can be:
\begin{align}
 a_i - \frac{a_ie^{a_i(x-b_i)}}{1+e^{a_i(x-b_i)}}
\end{align}
or 
\begin{align}
- \frac{a_ie^{a_i(x-b_i)}}{1+e^{a_i(x-b_i)}}
\end{align}
with $ai, bi$ real numbers on the interval $(0,1)$.

I know $F$ has the following graph's, if all $f_i$ are different:
 [image]

Since I know tha graph of my function I wanted to use the [bissection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method%22Bisection_method%22). The problem is that I don't know a good interval for my algorithm, which is the $a$ and $b$ of the graph above. I could use $a=-100$ and $b=100$, but since I adding $100$ functions, $F$ at $a=-100$ could be a very large, or very small number, which is a problem in Java, also the root could be out of the interval $[-100,100]$, maybe if this happens I can use a "if, else" to increase my interval to $[-200,200]$, and so on? The main problem is defining a interval for the bissection method.

What is a good root find algorithm for this problem?

Maybe Newton's method, since doesn't require a interval?

I don't know the right tags for this question, or if this is a appropriate site.

Comment: Other than having a smooth function, I don't think you told us much about function $F$ that helps in root finding.  Some aspects of your application (e.g. how many times will you have to solve such problems) are likely more relevant to numerical advice.

Comment: I have to find a root for $F$, $2000$ times.

Comment: Now $F$ involves (nominally) one hundred terms $f_i$, each of which depends on two parameters $a_i,b_i$.  When you say two thousand times you will find a root, do all of the parameters $a_i,b_i$ change between solvings?

Comment: Yes, all $a_i,b_i$ changes, so I solve $2000$ different equations.

Comment: Newton's method is worse than bisection in terms of what you need to know -- you have to know not only an _interval_ but a concrete starting guess which needs to be "close to" the root.

Comment: And in this case it would be disastrous to start Newton-Raphson without being close to the root. Your $F$ will be roughly tanh-shaped, and using Newton-Raphson to solve $\tanh x=0$ will _diverge explosively_ if the initial guess is more than about $1.09$ away from the root.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of problems, in the chapter *"Bracketing and Bisection"*, [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/) provides some interesting subroutines.

- **zbrac** : *"given a function and an initial guessed range $x_1$ to $x_2$, the subroutine expands the range geometrically until the root is bracketed by the returned values $x_1$ and $x_2$"*
- **zbrak** : *"given a function defined on the interval from $x_1$ to $x_2$, the subroutine subdivides the interval into $n$ equally spaced segments and searches for zero crossings of the function"*

When the range is known, one of my favored subroutines is **rtsafe** which combines bisection and Newton-Raphson methods in the given interval.

Answer (score 1):

Solving your equation $2000$ times is *nothing* compared to the time it will take you to code even a stupid solution. So any time you spend on being clever is wasted. Be stupid!

Each of your $f_i$s is a sigmoid function which will pretty much have reached its left or right limit when $|a_i(x-b_i)|\ge 20$. So compute all the solutions to $a_i(x-b_i)=\pm 20$, and take the interval between leftmost and rightmost of the solutions. Then use bisection!

To avoid overflow when $a_i(x-b_i)$ is large, use
$$ \frac{e^t}{1+e^t} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}} $$
to compute it whenever $a_i(x-b_i)>0$.

Comment: Why $20$? Also, since $a_i,b_i$ is on the interval $(0,1)$, $a_i(x-bi)$ is going to be large?

Comment: @Pinteco: Because $e^{-20}$ is very small and the difference between $\frac{e^t}{1+e^t}$ and the horizontal asymptote goes as $e^{-|t|}$ when $t$ is far from $0$.

Comment: So, for the first of the $2000$ equations, I solve $a_1(x-b_1)=\pm 20$, $a_2(x-b_2)=\pm 20$,..., $a_{100}(x-b_{100})=\pm 20$, then using the largest $x$ of the solutions, and the smallest $x$, (of a $100$ different $x's$) I use the bissection?

Comment: @Pinteco: That's what I would do. If I had tens of millions of instances to solve, I would start wondering whether I could find tighter initial bounds for the bisection, and whether switching to Newton-Raphson at some point would be advantageous.